# I'm trying to write a text on canvas but nothing happens

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm  tryin to write a text on canvas and set as GL10 object texture like this:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    bitmap.eraseColor(0);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.translate(width, height);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(0xffffffff & Color.MAGENTA);
    paint.setAlpha(255);
    canvas.drawText("Hello world", 0, 30, paint);
```

the texture color is drawn  if i change but the text not apears. 
some one know why ?

Comment: What does your question have to do with OpenGL ES when it uses just Canvas?

Comment: Why are you calling "save()" in the middle of your code? Do you restore the state somewhere?

Comment: Another question - do you use a view to represent your canvas somewhere? The code snippet seems to be incomplete.

Comment: @Reaper Because  i'm trying to make that canvas as texture to a opengl object

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev the "save()" it was just a guess and i'm  trying to use this canvas as a texture for a 3d object.

Comment: Not sure eventually. As far as i understood you are trying to draw a text on SurfaceView. I checked your text paint in my simple View and everything looks fine except for you defining text baseline in y: 0f, that may hide it out of the window scope. Try to increase y coordinate in drawText, probably it will help

Comment: I tried to make some changs but the problem still keep, if you want i can up the entire project on git, i wonder it will help you to get a better vision of the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the alpha setting is missing on the paint object that draws the text:

```
paint.setAlpha(255); //This line must be after paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

or

```
paint.setColor(0xffffffff & Color.MAGENTA);
```

Comment: Please check the width and height of the bitmap, you are drawing the text at 100, 200. And comment the line: paint.setTextSize(100);

Comment: still not working, if you want i can upload the entire project on my git, maybe it will help you to indetify the problem.